# Getting value of unselect option in jQuery chosen plugin

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am not getting value of unselect option while text is getting

```
$('#f_profession').chosen().change(function (evt, params) {
    alert($(this).text())
    if (params.deselected) {
        alert($(this).val())
    }
});
```

Comment: I found this in the docs *Note: in order to use change in the Prototype version, you have to include the Event.simulate class. The selected and deselected parameters are not available for Prototype* Are you using the Prototype version?

Comment: How I can check its prototype or not?

Comment: You need to go back and read the documentation of the plugin and then determine what you downloaded.

Comment: I rad it but couldn't find there , i just got how get  change event like this:
`$('#f_profession').chosen().change(function (evt, params) {});`
nothing else how to find the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#f_profession').chosen().change(function () {
        $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').each(function(){
        alert('Text : '+$(this).text());
        alert('Value : '+$(this).val());
         });
    });
});
```